# Centos show unexpected behavior when run a time consuming command

Tags: centos, memory-leaks

I have had a problem with my centOS for a long time and I search all off the internet and not found anything helpful.
My problem is when I run some commands like `python manage.py makemigrations` (this is django command) or `yum update` or in general a time consuming command, these suddenly goes to background and show  this message:

[image]

[image]

when I run `fg` commands it goes to foreground and dose nothing for a long time and will not be erased from RAM.
Does anyone know what the problem is or why it occurs?

Comment: It says stopped, so how do you presume it's still running the background? Did you check `ps`?

Comment: @tillyboy when I run `top` or `htop`, its process still have resources and not stopped. Now I check `ps` and show that the process is also running

Comment: Is it reproducible? Can you run it again, have the same thing happening and a *new* process appears in top/htop/ps?

Comment: @tillyboy Yes, a new process appears in top